# Azimuth image extent in frequency domain SAR algorithms (RDA, omega-k)

Tags: fft, ifft, radar, aliasing, zero-padding

When looking at the practical implementation of frequency domain SAR imaging algorithms like the range Doppler algorithm (RDA) and the omega-k algorithm (also called range migration algorithm, RMA) as described in "Digital Processing of SAR Data" by Cumming and Wong, one of the key steps is to perform an FFT along azimuth / slow time to create the Doppler spectrum.

Let us assume that we record $N_a$ azimuth samples with a pulse repetition frequency $f_{prf}$.

The ambiguity free region of the periodic Doppler spectrum according to the Nyquist sampling theorem is then given by
$$
f_{d} \in \left[-\frac{f_{prf}}{2}; \frac{f_{prf}}{2} \right].
$$

The idea in both algorithms is then to modify the phases of the radar baseband signal history either in the range Doppler or omega-k domain to compensate range cell migration and perform azimuth compression by (approximate) matched filtering.

The final step in both algorithms is an IFFT along the azimuth / slow time, turning the Doppler phase history into a cross-range / azimuth coordinate.

The output signal obtained from the IFFT in azimuth is periodic with period
$$
\frac{N_a}{f_{prf}},
$$
i.e. the output signal length is identical to the length over which data was recorded.

Multiplying with the platform speed $v$ this yields an azimuth scene extent
$$
x_a \in \left[-\frac{N_a v}{2 f_{prf}}; \frac{N_a v}{2 f_{prf}} \right] = \left[-\frac{L}{2}; \frac{L}{2}\right].
$$

This is unfortunate, as in small short-range radar systems the distance $L$ traveled during the recording of the signal history might be on the order of 0.5 meters, whereas a wide beam width patch antenna allows recording of features that are at azimuth positions $x_a >> L/2$, without any aliasing in the Doppler spectrum.

The result is that the targets at $x_a > L/2$ are well focused, because there is no aliasing in the Doppler domain, but after the IFFT they get folded back into the range $[-L/2; L/2]$ and are therefore not correctly registered in azimuth.

One obvious solution is to zero-pad the raw signal before the azimuth FFT and then perform the processing on the resulting interpolated Doppler spectrum.
This allows the output of the IFFT in azimuth to cover a larger azimuth scene extent, at the cost of dramatically increasing the computational cost of the image formation algorithm.

AFAICT zero-padding the spectrum just before the IFFT won't help, because it merely interpolates the output signal without increasing the maximum signal length (for example doubling the number of output samples while halving the sample spacing --> same overall signal length).

Is there another way to increase the azimuth scene extent without increasing the computational cost significantly?